# How to install x-tile on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS?

Tags: package-management, xorg, mate, tiling

In previous releases [`x-tile`](https://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/) was packaged as [official package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=x-tile), but 18.04 LTS does not have such package.

How can I install `x-tile` on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As before `x-tile` package is located in the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic).

So we need to add PPA and install package from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x-tile
```

Then find it in *Applications->Accessories->x-tile*.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: I tried to contact PPA owner, hope we'll get package for 21.10 soon. If you are in hurry - install hirsute's package manually by `wget -c https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/x-tile_3.3-0_all.deb && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ./x-tile_3.3-0_all.deb` .