# Is there a tiling extension that works on Mate?

Tags: 18.04, window-manager, ubuntu-mate, gnome-shell-extension, tiling

Last year I was using Ubuntu GNOME, and one of the things I really liked about it was the extension `gtile` which makes it much easier to work on a 21:9 monitor. Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu MATE? If not, is there something that will easily let me snap windows to left third, middle third, right third when my laptop is connected to a monitor, but will snap to half when I'm not plugged in?

Comment: I have never used gtile, so I do not know its functionality. But you can try other tiling application - [`x-tile`](https://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/) (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029203/66509)).

Comment: The basic thing I like about it is it isn't a tiling window manager. It's a program that tiles your windows when you want it to, but otherwise stays out of your way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Window shuffler for Ubuntu Budgie & Mate

As part of the Ubuntu Budgie team, I developed a tool for window arrangement. Although it was written for Budgie, it (at least) works on Mate as well.
[Window shuffler](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler), recently was made available in its own repo:

[image]

### GUI and CLI options

### *GUI*

Window Shuffler can be used from either GUI or CLI. The GUI options are pretty much shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii4n8H4XEzc).

### *Command line*

Looking at the command line options, they should include pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

From the README:

*Shuffler can also be used by cli. To use, run `shuffler_nogui`, with as arguments the size of the matrix (horizontally, vertically) + the targeted position of the active window in the matrix (where 0 is the first). An example:*

```
shuffler_nogui 2 2 0 1
```

*will place the active window in the bottom left cell in a grid of 2 x 2.*

#### Install

To install, just follow the instructions in the README

Comment: Ooh, this looks nice

Comment: @OscarSmith In case you have any questions or anything, just mention.

Comment: You should put a disclaimer on this answer saying that it's your tool

Comment: @OscarSmith The fact who wrote it is totally irrelevant imo. I am not advertising myself, nor anything I represent. I would post it no matter who wrote it and my interest if anyone is using it (or not) is none. Added it to the answer nevertheless.

Comment: @OscarSmith Just curious, but did you try?

Comment: how do you start it to get a 3x2 grid? Could gridsize be made changable while open?

Comment: @OscarSmith sure! With the grid open, use the arrow keys to change the grid. The on next run, the grid will appear like the last time. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that should probably be documented

Comment: @JacobVlijm does your extension work in Ubuntu Mate 18.10? Maybe you can help here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122388/18-10-mate-python-gconf-not-installable

Comment: @DKBose ah, thanks! it does, posted an answer.