# x-tile / python-gconf not installable on 18.10 MATE

Tags: python, 18.10, window-manager, mate, gconf

On 18.10 MATE I'm trying to install x-tile https://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/ which I've been using since 16.04 or so.

Installation fails looking for python-gconf and installation of python-gconf fails with what looks to be a circular dependency. Is there an issue with python-gconf for 18.10? Has it been replaced? I've left a note on the developer site but there hasn't been x-tile activity there for some time.

Here's what the installation attempt looks like. I've cut some output into `<...>`

```
 sudo dpkg -i x-tile_2.5.1-1_all.deb 
 <...>
  x-tile depends on python-gconf; however:
   Package python-gconf is not installed.
<...>
sudo apt install python-gconf
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  python-gconf : Depends: gconf-service
                 Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5) but it is not going to be installed
 <...>
  gconf-service : Depends: gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-4.1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
  <...>
  gconf-service-backend : Depends: gconf-service
                          Depends: libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-4.1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-4.1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
  x-tile : Depends: python-gconf but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt --fix-broken install` simply removes x-tile.

---

```
  apt-cache policy python-gconf apt
  python-gconf:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 2.28.1+dfsg-1.2
    Version table:
       2.28.1+dfsg-1.2 500
          500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
  apt:
    Installed: 1.7.2
    Candidate: 1.7.2
    Version table:
   *** 1.7.2 500
          500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       1.7.0ubuntu0.1 500
          500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
       1.7.0 500
          500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages



  And 

   apt-cache policy libgconf-2-4:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 3.2.6-4.1ubuntu2
   Version table:
      3.2.6-4.1ubuntu2 500
         500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: A quick look at one error (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgconf-2-4&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all) makes it look like your requirements should be met (3.2.6-4.1), it's located in 'universe' so firstly I'd check you have 'universe' enabled, second I'd use `apt-cache policy libgconf-2-4` to verify it's in your sources - if it isn't listed I'd check your sources (if using a mirror, ensure it's up-to-date (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) as it may be your chosen mirror needs replacement (isn't maintained reliably)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but see [Is there a tiling extension that works on Mate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044161/is-there-a-tiling-extension-that-works-on-mate). While it's for 18.04, it may also be there for 18.10. Bonus: the developer is active here!

Comment: @StephenBoston - please add output of `apt-cache policy python-gconf apt` to the question. See my answer below for details. Please make sure that your repositories are correct, I can't reproduce the problem on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.10 VM. Do you really mean 18.10?

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the output.Yes. This is 18.10 MATE

Comment: @guiverc I have added the output.

Comment: It is Disco, it is 19.04!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @N0rbert Ha! I ran these policy queries on the wrong machine! I have corrected the question with output from the 18.10 machine. Sorry about that. The Disco machine has the same issue with x-tile.

Comment: @StephenBoston Then it should simply install and work as expected. I have exactly the same versions on my machine. To be completely sure, please change mirror to *Main Server* in `software-properties-gtk`, install all updates and retry. Please carefully read my answer below. The 18.10 has `python-gconf` and dependencies in repository, on 19.04 you can install packages from 18.10.

Comment: @N0rbert Indeed! That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages about missed packages pointed me to the idea that you have disabled *universe* pocket. You should enable it first and install updates:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then proceed with your method by `sudo apt-get install ./x-tile_2.5.1-1_all.deb` or with method below.

---

The Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) is not supported (yet) in official PPA. But X-Tile was available [for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/%7Egiuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic) (as you can see in [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029203/66509)).

Temporarily you can install the `x-tile` package from PPA manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/x-tile_2.5.1-3_all.deb
sudo apt install -y ./x-tile_2.5.1-3_all.deb
```

and enjoy it as before:

> [image: x-tile on Ubuntu MATE 18.10]

**Update:** I have e-mailed *giuspen* to get official package for 18.10 and upcoming 19.04.

---

In case of upcoming Ubuntu 19.10 (Disco Dingo), the `x-tile` package is still installable if you get `python-gconf` manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python/python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.2_amd64.deb

wget https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/x-tile_2.5.1-3_all.deb
sudo apt install -y ./x-tile_2.5.1-3_all.deb
```

Comment: System responds with :````'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.````

Comment: Even the latest ppa is based on python 2, gconf is no more. Just curious, was it your downvote?

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes, it was me. With all respect to your work, your current answer does not provide solution for OP problem. He wants X-TIle, not its alternative.

Comment: It does, just not like op had in mind. Furthermore, the question is if you should advice -if it works at all- to install ancient stuff that will anyway not work in future. As said x-tile hasn't been updated for three years. Means it is abandoned untill picked up again, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

#### About Gconf and python2

Not he answer you were literally looking for, but [gconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) is gone for quite a while (replaced by [dconf](https://askubuntu.com/a/249916/72216)), and python2, in which x-tile is written, [isn't quite fresh as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3u764e/ubuntu_finally_dropping_python_27_in_the_default/). Looking at the code of [x-tile](https://github.com/giuspen/x-tile), its latest commit was almost three years ago, which is a very long time in developers time.

#### Then what?

Your options are to either try and contact x-tile's maintainer and find out if he is going to update, or use another tiling extension, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044161/is-there-a-tiling-extension-that-works-on-mate), which is a default extension in Ubuntu Budgie, but also works on Mate (disclaimer: I am the author).

The extension furthermore has a growing number of cli options and can a.o. be used for quarter-tiling shortcuts, arrange all in a grid etc etc.

[image]

To install, just follow the instructions in the README [here](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler).

Comment: I will give it a try and get back.

Comment: I have x-tile working now thanks to N0rbert but I agree with you that giuspen seems to have abandoned it so I will try out your offering. I like what I see so far. I'll let you know if I find any issues or if I decide to stop using it.